# Will bleach kill Vesicle-Cloaked Murine Norovirus Clusters?

Tags: virus, infectious-diseases, disinfection

Referencing the following article. But there is no mention of bleach specifically so I am wondering if simply cleaning the surface with bleach would do the trick? Or the article is also refering to bleach perhaps? Hard to say/

Below is the article.

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.1c01763?cookieSet=1

Comment: It's not looking promising.... https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.2c00732

Comment: Thank you. Interesting article and very surprising. It seems there is a need for more research.